# Are there any ports of SLATEC?

Tags: programming-languages, fortran

Are there any other libraries of code implementing SLATEC? Finding a Fortran compiler is possible, but if there's anything else out there it'd be helpful.

Comment: Are there any specific functions from SLATEC you're interested in, or the library as a whole?

Comment: Indeed it was, @Idigas. And I have a copy of the source. What I'd like to know is if anyone has successfully ported it to another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search reveals [MATLAB port](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14535), apparently.

Comment: Well, I was kind of hoping for something like Pascal, C, Forth, ... Anyway, you get the vote.